# why does comparing two objects with === operation return false

Tags: node.js

I have the following code

```
    console.log(typeof id1, typeof id2)
    console.log(id1, id2)
    if (id1 === id2) {

        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
```

If I execute the following code I end up with id1 of type Object and the  same for id2.
when I compare them with === it returns false even thought they are of the same type.
I know that if I use == this will be true because type checking is not enforced. Can someone clarify why it returns false with === operator even though the type is the same.

The following is the result printed using console.log

```
object , object
5e90603e7f0d251cab9253c6 , 5e90603e7f0d251cab9253c6
```

The ids are mongoose ObjectId

Comment: What are the values of those objects?  Can you provide a complete runnable example in a code snippet?

Comment: I have included extra information in the questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because objects in javascript are reference variables, whats happening there is the memory allocation are the one being compared.

If your comparing objectIds what you can do is:

```
id1.toString() === id2.toString()
```